# How do I download a machine learning model in order to send it to someone?

Tags: r, machine-learning

I've trained a GBM model, and it's ready to work. I just want to share it with someone (make it as a file and send it)..

How can I do that in R?

Thanks!

Comment: `save` (as M.Viking said) or `saveRDS`, the classic R functions for saving objects to files for perfect transfer to another R instance (different user, different computer, doesn't matter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the base `save()` function

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/save

```
save(gbm.model.name, file="saved_model.RData")
```

And your colleague can `load()`

```
gbm.model.name <- load(file="saved_model.RData")
```

There is a way to exchange models between languages called PMML https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predictive_Model_Markup_Language
This post describes https://stackoverflow.com/a/28625679/10276092